# Excel Formula Help (VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay. I have a SKU in column B in Sheet1, and the price in column A in Sheet1. I also have a few thousand of these SKUs in Sheet2, column A, and their respective prices in Sheet2, column B.

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP to look inside sheet2 for the sku and their price. If the SKU exists, return it's new price, and if the SKU doesn't exist, return the original price from sheet1, columnA. And if it's a blank cell, return "DELETE".

If anyone could tell me the formula to do this you'll be my all time hero.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, put this formula in Sheet1 C1: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),IF(A1<>"",A1,"DELETE"))`. Let us know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!B1),"DELETE",IFNA(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B:B,0)),Sheet2!B1))
```

VLookup won't work, since it uses the left-most column in the table as the key, but you can use INDEX/MATCH to use an arbitrary column as the key.